# Object Autoconvert to Double with Serialization/GSON

Tags: java, serialization, gson

I ran into a problem when developing an application that uses Gson to serialize objects and deserialize them. However, I ran into a problem that I cannot explain the cause of and after a while, I narrowed down the problem to this SSCCE:

```
import com.google.gson.Gson;

/**
 * demonstrates the issue at hand
 */
public class Probs {
    public Probs () {
        //holds the byte array form of the JSON data
        byte[] info = new byte[1];

        //get the JSON for a data object and store it in the byte array
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        Data before = new Data(1);
        info = gson.toJson(before).getBytes();

        //reassemble the JSON data as a string
        String json = new String(info);
        System.out.println("JSON string: " + json);

        //reconstruct the Data object from the JSON data
        Data after = gson.fromJson(json, Data.class);

        //attempt to get the "num" value and convert it to an integer
        Object val = after.getNum();
        System.out.println("Class name: " + val.getClass().getName()); //is java.lang.Double (why isn't it java.lang.Object?)
        Integer num = (Integer)val; //produces "java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Double cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer"
        System.out.println("Number: " + num);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Probs();
    }
}

/**
 * holds the one piece of data
 */
class Data {
    Object num;
    public Data(int num) {
        this.num = num;
        System.out.println("Object value: " + this.num);
    }

    public Object getNum () {
        return this.num;
    }
}
```

I did read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19523728/gson-is-there-a-way-to-preserve-type-information-if-serialization-deserializat?rq=1) but it did not appear to have any accepted answers. Because of the way I use it in my application, I need to have the Data object store its data as an Object and be able to cast it later to a different type. When I deserialize the data object and call its getNum(), I thought that should return an Object (since that is its return type). In my application, I need to be able to convert that type into an Integer. However, the JVM appears to convert the Object (val) into a Double because the getClass() reveals that it is a Double and not an Object. Then when I try to convert it to an integer via a cast it fails because it is apparently a Double and not an Object.

My question is: why is val a Double and not an Object (what am I not understanding)?

Thank you for your help

Comment: You can assign `int` to `Object` (`Data` constructor)?

Comment: @Smutje It compiled and just to test it I put System.out.println(this.num) after the assignment to this.num to make sure it worked (now reflected in the above code) and it appeared to work correctly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is the JSON spec, and what you're doing.

The [JSON spec](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4627.txt) only specifies a *single* numeric type, which can a include a decimal point and a fractional portion:

> 2.4.  Numbers
>
> The representation of numbers is similar to that used in most
>   programming languages.  A number contains an integer component that
>   may be prefixed with an optional minus sign, which may be followed by 
>   a fraction part and/or an exponent part.

JSON parsers are left to decide for themselves what to do with that numeric type when parsing/mapping the JSON.

In your case, your `Data` class has `num` defined as `Object`. This gives Gson no hint as to what specific Java numeric type you'd like the JSON numeric type mapped to. The authors of Gson decided to use a `Double` when this is the case regardless of whether the number in the JSON includes a decimal + fraction or not.

This actually makes perfect sense when you consider that an integer can be expressed as a double, but not the other way around. Using a single type rather than parsing the number and deciding if it's a int or a double provides consistent behavior.

It's unclear why you aren't using `Integer` (or `int`) for `num` in your `Data` object if that's what you expect/need. You state you need to cast to `Integer` "later" which means the only thing that object can be in the first place is an `Integer`; any other casting attempt would fail.

Comment: Thank you, I guess I just didn't find that in the JSON specifications. I used an Object data type because that same Data object needs to be able to store Strings and booleans as well and that was the most streamlined way I could find to do it (I'm sure there is a better one, I just couldn't find it).

Comment: @cryptopi I'd need to test, but I'm pretty sure if you change the type to `String` in your object you'll have a better time of it. I know Gson will convert numeric types to `String`, just need to check boolean types. Then you can just parse the string to the type you need.

Comment: that's a good idea - I just checked it and it seems to work for `Boolean` types as well. Thanks!