# Gson deserializes array of integer numbers as ArrayList of Doubles instead of ArrayList of Integers (or array of int) as a value of Map<String,Object>

Tags: java, gson, deserialization

There is a JSON string

```
{"uuid": "a1e55ef2-3a58-40d7-9ca2-49b0c3aa653c","args": {"ids": [5,77,999], type: "item_delete"}}
```

which I'm trying to deserialize to the following class

```
class Foo {
    String uuid;
    Map<String,Object> args;
}
```

with this code

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String commandJson = ...;
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    Foo foo = gson.fromJson(commandJson, Foo.class);
}
```

Then, in the debugger I can see that `ids` property is represented as `ArrayList<Double>`, thus instead of `5,77,999` I can see `5.0,77.0,999.0`.

I tried to customize GsonBuilder with a lot of different `JsonDeserializer`s and `TypeAdapter`s, for example

```
    GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder()
            .registerTypeHierarchyAdapter(Double.class, new JsonDeserializer<Integer>() { // also tried Number.class
                @Override
                public Integer deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context)
                        throws JsonParseException {
                    return null; // No implementation in this example as it is not even called
                }
             });
    Gson gson = gsonBuilder.create();
```

or

```
class IntegerTypeAdapter extends TypeAdapter<Integer> {
    @Override
    public void write(JsonWriter out, Integer value) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("hello from write");
    }
    @Override
    public Integer read(JsonReader in) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("hello from read");
        return null; // I didn't implement it as it looks like it is not even called
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder()
            .registerTypeAdapter(Integer.class, new IntegerTypeAdapter());
        Gson gson = gsonBuilder.create();
}
```

registered with `registerTypeAdapter` and `registerTypeHierarchyAdapter` methods but **it looks like their code is not event executed**. I tried to print something from inside my `TypeAdapter` or `JsonDeserializer` code - it is not printed, and code execution is not stopped at breakpoints inside their code.

Gson version: 2.2.4

Comment: It's worth pointing out that the JSON format itself doesn't have an integer type. The primitive number type in ECMAScript (and thus in JSON which is a subset of its syntax) is an IEEE-754 double-precision floating point number. So in effect all numeric values in JSON *are* `Double`s.

Comment: OK. I can use doubles from deserialized code, but then what if I need to serialize it again to JSON? Object ids represented as doubles (with a dot and zero) won't work.

Comment: I don't know what you're asking. A `double` value of `42.0` **is** a `double` value of `42` (and `42.00`, etc.). If you care about the string representation then you need to be serializing these things as strings in the first place, not numbers.

Comment: @gumkins http://stackoverflow.com/a/36529534/1032167 you can probably try simething like this