# Convert Arraylist of HashMaps to Json String (GSON)

Tags: android, arrays, json, hashmap, gson

I have created 3 HashMaps all stored into an Arraylist but I cannot make it into a JSON String, I am using the GSON library.

Any help would kindly be appreciated.

Below you can see all the 3 hashmaps and the ArrayList x am adding them to.

```
    private void createAdditionalPackages() {

    if (chemoBtn.isChecked()) {
        chemo.put("name", "chemo");
        chemo.put("price", chemoButtonPrice);
    }

    if (cremBtn.isChecked()) {

        cremation.put("name", "crematie");
        cremation.put("price", cremationButtonPrice);
    }

    if (travenBtn.isChecked()) {

        travel.put("name", "reisverz");
        travel.put("price", travelButtonPrice);
    }

    x.add(chemo);
    x.add(cremation);
    x.add(travel);

    List<JsonObject> jsonObjectList = new ArrayList<>() ;
    for(HashMap<String, String> data : x){
        JsonObject object = new JsonObject(data);
        jsonObjectList.add(object);
    }

    JsonArray additional_coverages = new JsonArray(jsonObjectList);
```

See error :

[image]

Comment: please check this link if you want to convert Arraylist or Hashmap into string via GSON     https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37091548/convert-arraylist-with-gson-to-string

Answer (score 0):

```
    JsonArray additional_coverages = new JsonArray();
    // Iterate over your Hashmap
    for (Map.Entry<String,String> data : x.entrySet()) {
        // Create your JsonObject and use addProperty
        JsonObject object = new JsonObject();
        object.addProperty(data.getKey(), data.getValue());
        // Add data in your JsonArray
        additional_coverages.add(object);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot directly add list of JsonObject to JsonArray

you can use something like this.

```
JsonArray additional_coverages = new JsonArray();

for(singleItem in jsonObjectList){
additional_coverages.put(singleItem )
}
```