# Gson converting int into double when parsing json string

Tags: android, json, gson

I have [this](http://hastebin.com/dikosivipu.json) JSON file into my assets. I am parsing it using Gson into the following model class:

```
public class SearchRequest {

    private ArrayList<String> _source;
    private int from;
    private int size;
    private Object sort;
    private Object query;


    public void setFrom(int from) {
        this.from = from;
    }

    public void setSize(int size) {
        this.size = size;
    }

    public void setArtist(String artistName) {
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        JsonObject object = gson.toJsonTree(query).getAsJsonObject();
        JsonArray should = object.getAsJsonObject("function_score").getAsJsonObject("query")
                .getAsJsonObject("bool").getAsJsonArray("should");
        should.get(0).getAsJsonObject().getAsJsonObject("match").addProperty("album_artist", artistName);
        should.get(1).getAsJsonObject().getAsJsonObject("nested").getAsJsonObject("query")
                .getAsJsonObject("bool").getAsJsonArray("must").get(0).getAsJsonObject()
                .getAsJsonObject("match").addProperty("tracks.artist", artistName);
        query = gson.fromJson(object.toString(), query.getClass());
    }
}
```

When I convert this JSON into an object of this class, the `query` object becomes a `LinkedTreeMap`. But in this conversion, the key `offset` which is an integer, becomes double. In my JSON (line number 50), `offset` is `0`, but after conversion, its `0.0`. Screenshot:

[image]

Why is this happening? How to fix this?

Comment: You declare query as an object. You can create complete bean for internal objects

Comment: @Dharmendra Yeah, but there will be a lot of beans, I want to avoid that. Also there are 3 more similar requests, but the query object is a bit different, so there will be even more model classes.

Comment: You can look into similar issue from http://stackoverflow.com/a/36529534/630668

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to fix this?

It's not a subject to be fixed and nothing to be worried about.

> Why is this happening?

Your JSON<->Java mapping does not provide any mappings except the top-most one. That makes Gson work like that due to lack of the target type information, and `LinkedTreeMap` is used *internally*. Literals like `0` that may look like integers are also legal floating point values from the JSON format point of view: the JSON specification declares *numbers* only, and does not make any corrections on "integerness". Having no enough information on deserializing the data types, Gson applies the default parsing policies, and chooses `java.lang.Double` as a type that can hold any other standard numeric values that can hold less significance bits (`long`s can fit the room of `double`s easily; but not sure what Gson does for `BigDecimal`s -- JSON specifications does not seem to make any limits). So this is just internal Gson representation and you have a few options on that:

- You can declare a mapping (write or generate by a specialized tool) that would even avoid internal `LinkedTreeMap`s. Tedious? Maybe. But much more power in type safety, `javac` control, or your favorite IDE navigation and suggestions.
- Gson provides a bunch of methods to convert a JSON tree value to a target type: `getAsJsonObject()`, `getAsJsonArray()`, `getAsInt()`, and more allowing to get the target object in the representation you want. For example,

```
final Object value = searchRequest.query
        .get("function_score").getAsJsonObject()
        .get("functions").getAsJsonArray()
        .get(0).getAsJsonObject()
        .get("linear").getAsJsonObject()
        .get("date").getAsJsonObject()
        .get("offset").getAsInt();
System.out.println(value + " " + value.getClass());
```

gives:

> 0 class java.lang.Integer

because of `get("offset").getAsInt()` that's internally implemented as `return isNumber() ? getAsNumber().intValue() : ...;` for JSON primitives.

- You can apply partial mappings. For example, you can extract the `date` JSON tree and convert it to a special mapping having the `private int offset;` field declared: `gson.fromJson(dateJsonObject, DateMapping.class)`.

Again, Gson just does not have enough type information and works really fine.