# JAVA : On Converting Json Element to an Object, Integer value gets Converted to Double

Tags: java, gson, deserialization, data-conversion, fromjson

I have a Class defined with an attribute of Object Data Type

```
public class Field {
  private Object value = null;
}
```

On performing below operation

```
Map<String,Object> map Object = new HashMap<String,Object>();
Field field = new Field();
f1.value = 1;
Map<String, Object> fieldMap = new ObjectMapper().convertValue(field, Field.class);
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder();
JsonElement jsonElement = gson.toJsonTree(fieldMap);
Field field = gson.fromJson(jsonElement, Field.class);
```

If we access **field.value**, it returns **1.0** instead of 1.
I observed that this conversion happens before the Primitive conversion of GSON.
Looks like the Object data type is casting the String in JSON "1" to Double instead of Integer.

Is there any way I can override this default behavior?

I tried using Jackson Convertor instead of GSON, but did not work.
I am expecting the response to be an Integer instead of Double value.

Comment: Any particular reason for you to use `Object` instead of just `Integer`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Gson converting int into double when parsing json string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41853066/gson-converting-int-into-double-when-parsing-json-string)

Comment: Firstly, the example code you have added has lot of `basic` programmatical  errors do fix the example code. Secondly, is there any specific reason why you are using both `ObjectMapper(jackson)` and `Gson` ? You can do the conversion from `Map` to `Field` object using jackson ObjectMapper also

Comment: I need to use Object as the values can be integer or String.
I actually need to convert it to map using jackson and store it so that I can pass it from one layer to another layer. (Which I cannot show here.)
Also the actual class is very complex and has many more attribute.
When it is converted to Map<> it create a list of items. To consider conversion of all elements I need to use gson.

Comment: @Prog_G The linked answer does not solve this problem because, we do not know the actual data type of the value stored. It varies from case to case hence we cannot use inbuild option options to get value as Integer.

Comment: you can use `objectMapper.convertValue(map,Field.class)` to convert map to the desired class object and it retains the datatype from the map

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following will be about the part of your code using Gson. In general avoid mixing multiple JSON libraries, either use Gson or Jackson, but not both at the same time (and especially not in the same method). It will just cause confusion and issues, e.g. Jackson annotations not being recognized by Gson and vice versa.

---

When you deserialize a JSON number as `Object`, Gson by default parses it always as `Double`, regardless of the format of the number.
Gson does not try to guess the number type because the desired type is application-specific. For example one application might want `1` to parsed as `Double`, another as `Integer` and another one as `Long`; there is no 'right' choice here.

If possible you should change the type `Object` to a more specific type such as `Integer`. If that is not possible you have the following alternatives:

- Use [`GsonBuilder#setObjectToNumberStrategy`](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/com.google.code.gson/gson/latest/com.google.gson/com/google/gson/GsonBuilder.html#setObjectToNumberStrategy(com.google.gson.ToNumberStrategy)) to specify how Gson should convert a JSON number to an `Object`.
  You can use one of the predefined [`ToNumberPolicy` variants](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/com.google.code.gson/gson/latest/com.google.gson/com/google/gson/ToNumberPolicy.html), or write your own `ToNumberStrategy`; you can use Gson's `ToNumberPolicy` code as help for how to do this.
- Annotate the `Object` field with [`@JsonAdapter`](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/com.google.code.gson/gson/latest/com.google.gson/com/google/gson/annotations/JsonAdapter.html) and create a custom `TypeAdapter` which parses the value.

Comment: I was able to achieve desired result with this approach.